# How to enable ES2020 in react-native app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs, ecmascript-2020

I was trying to add ES2020 features in my react-native app, I installed `"babel-preset-es2020": "^1.0.2"` and added `.babelrc` file like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2020"]
}
```

But nothing seems to work, this error is coming there:

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module `./animations/TimingAnimation` from `node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\Animated.js`:

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\animations\TimingAnimation(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\animations\TimingAnimation\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\smond\dev\sg_app\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\Users\smond\dev\sg_app\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\smond\dev\sg_app\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:287:16)
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\smond\dev\sg_app\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:267:42)
    at C:\Users\smond\dev\sg_app\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:434:31
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (C:\Users\smond\dev\sg_app\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:431:18)
    at C:\Users\smond\dev\sg_app\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:275:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\smond\dev\sg_app\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
```

Please tell me a way to enable ES2020 there

Answer (score 0):

Your error appears to be related to react-native-reanimated package not ES version. Make sure that react-native-reanimated is installed at your package.json, else:

```
npm i react-native-reanimated
```

Comment: I solved it with `npm start -- --reset-cache`, Thanks for response btw @Elise Chant